# Нужна ли запятая перед "и" в приведенном предложении?

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед "и" в предложении: "Пит и Нил нашли собственный выход (,) и довольно-таки изобретательный"?

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна, здесь присоединительная конструкция (союз "и" имеет смысл "причём"):

> При союзном присоединении обычно употребляется запятая: *Перед вами
>   люди, имеющие в городе власть, и не малую (Н. И.).* Иногда ставится
>   тире: *Дело мы делаем великое и сделали уже немало, а недостатки есть -
>   и серьезные (Чак.).*

http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-037.htm